# MATLAB iso file for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I checked at my University and they do not have a Matlab `.iso` file for Ubuntu.

Where can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can get it from the [MATLAB MathWorks site](http://uk.mathworks.com/downloads/).

You need to login to use this, so you should have a University account that can be used.

If not, you can ask the University to download it for you, and give them a USB for it.

[You can follow the Ubuntu Wiki page to install it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB#Installation_Instructions)

Answer (score 0):

Most unfortunately, MatLab is neither open software nor free.  You could check with the University to see who holds the license to MatLab, and ask them to download the ISO file.

Comment: There are however FOSS (free & open-source software) alternatives to the commercial MATLAB (market leader) product. See: http://www.osalt.com/matlab eg. Sage 4.x, Octave 3.x, Scilab 4.1.x

Comment: @david6 Probably, but the op is specifically asking about the MatLab software set in a university setting.  I would make the reasonable assumption that this is a student, who has been assigned using MatLab for some project...

Comment: **@Charles_Green**: Well aware of that, and familiar with both Matlab and alternatives. Basically, the Uni should provide (or subsidise) MatLab. However, I am aware of students/researchers using FOSS alternatives which can run MATLAB source (or auto-translate).

Comment: Depending on the Uni as well they may have it available on the relevant department's computers. If you look through the University's site as well they may also have the relevant info on getting a (discounted/free) student license on various software